# Most suitable language(s) for simulations in modeling?

Tags: python, sage

I will participate a modeling competition, which spends three days.
I need a language which is fast and designed for modeling, such as to 2D/3D models.

I have considered these languages:

1. Python
2. Sage

Which languages would you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the language that you know best and that has good-enough tools for the task at hand. Depending on when the competition is you may have no time to learn a new language/environment.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at http://www.processing.org/ -- it is a programming language (similar to java) and IDE especially developed for simulation and data visualization. given that it was developed in a teaching context, it will be easy to use and will give you great results in no time -- i have seen amazing applications (e,g, [webpages as graphs](http://www.aharef.info/static/htmlgraph/), [complexification](http://www.complexification.net/))

Answer (score -1):

I would use C++, since it spends three days I would have time to write C++ code, and it's a lot faster then python, which would be my choice if it were a one day competition. So I would probably use C++ with OpenGL and SDL for the models. The simulations would I first write in C++, and if I had time at the end I would try to implement them in a shader if it were possible.